# Remove index.php from wordpress URLs in iis7

Tags: php, wordpress, iis-7, url-rewriting, permalinks

I want to remove index.php from url , i am using wordpress and iis7 .
how can i do this

Comment: Any of this answers solved your problem?

Answer (score 11):

Use this web.config

*(web.config is the IIS equivalent to .htaccess file in apache webservers. It can be found in the root folder. If there is none, you need to create one.)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
 <defaultDocument>
     <!-- Set the default document -->
      <files>
        <remove value="index.php" />
        <add value="index.php" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then in permalinks page, set "Custom Structure" and give the value `/%postname%/`

Note that **URL Rewrite module specific to IIS version needs to be installed** for this to function(Thanks to @Spikolynn's comment below)

Comment: where is web.config

Comment: web.config is the IIS equivalent to .htaccess file in apache webservers. It can be found in the root folder. If there is none, you need to create one.

Comment: I am not a wordpress developer, but after many days of research finally I have found the resolution.

Comment: You need the URL Rewrite module installed for this to function: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: @Spikolynn that is right. I will add it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Another pretty quick solution, in a situation where you uses Windows Azure websites, is to use `Microsoft WebMatrix` to login into your website and just create a web.config file [as this article pointed out](http://www.bousie.co.uk/blog/pretty-wordpress-permalinks-on-azure/). That solves it. No need to install a `URL Rewrite  extension` or anything like that yourself. MS Webmatrix seem to solve the problem easily.